# LINQ with SUM() JOIN

Tags: c#, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I'm trying to translate this SQL sentence to LINQ but I'm very new in LINQ

```
select professor.nom, professor.llinatge,
SUM(case when falta.aprovada = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as FJ,
SUM(case when falta.aprovada = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as FNJ
from falta inner join professor on falta.id_profe = professor.id_profe
group by professor.llinatge, professor.nom
```

I can't get work this in LINQ with JOINs. My best aproach to this in LINQ was:

```
var query = from f in db.falta
join p in db.professor
on f.id_profe equals p.id_profe
group f by new {p.nom, p.llinatge, f.aprovada} into g
select new 
{
    nombre = g.Key.nom + " "+ g.Key.llinatge,
    fj = g.Select(s=> s.aprovada == true).Count(),
    fnj = g.Select(s=> s.aprovada == false).Count()
 };
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you have `group by f.aprovada` in your LINQ version but not in the SQL version?

Comment: You are rigth it's not necessary for my query. I'm very stuck in this part...

Comment: "I can't get work" - Can you be more specific? What error do you get?

Comment: It's not an error. The result of this query is not that I expected from SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try [SQL to LINQ](http://www.sqltolinq.com/) ... and over the years I always found [Linq Pad](http://www.linqpad.net/) as a very handy tool...

Comment: Thank you. I already test these tools but can't convert SQL to LINQ with Linq Pad and SQL to LINQ is not free. I'm not a pro...

Comment: Thank you, finally I could download a trial version of Linqer!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the LINQ query that match my SQL statement:

```
from falta in db.Falta
join professor in db.Professor on falta.Id_profe equals professor.Id_profe
group new {professor, falta} by new {
  professor.Llinatge,
  professor.Nom
} into g
select new {
  g.Key.Nom,
  g.Key.Llinatge,
  FJ = (System.Int64?)g.Sum(p => (
  p.falta.Aprovada == true ? 1 : 0)),
  FNJ = (System.Int64?)g.Sum(p => (
  p.falta.Aprovada == false ? 1 : 0))
};
```

Thank you for your help! Hope this helps!